# Documenting duck type parameters in javascript

Tags: javascript, documentation

How do I properly document duck typed object parameters? Let's say I have a function:

```
function doSuff(animal){
    // do stuff
}
```

If i require that the animal should have a `walk`, `eat`, `speak`, and `sleep` methods, how do I state them in the documentation?

EDIT: By documentation, I mean something like JSDoc, or any other comment-style documentation. I will probably do a separate in-depth technical documentation, but I think it is nice to have a simple description of the parameter above the function code itself.

Comment: totally unclear

Comment: can you please explain what is unclear? I tried to explain it the best I can. The things that are unclear I will edit accordingly.

Comment: what do you mean by a documentation?

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: something like JSDoc/YUIdoc

Comment: Consider adding a TypeScript `.d.ts` file. Even for JavaScript users, most IDEs will pick it up and provide inline help/completion/checking.

Comment: Thanks. Will edit to explain further.

Answer (score 0):

I also think its good to write code that is self explanatory. Use JSDoc on the function, but also help the user to know whats missing directly in your code.

You can do something like:

```
let createAnimal = function (a) {
  if (!a.walk || !a.eat || !a.speak || !a.sleep) {
    throw new Error(`An animal must walk: '${a.walk}', eat: '${a.eat}', speak: '${a.speak}', sleep: '${a.sleep}'`);
  }
  return function doStuff() {
    console.log(a.swim)
  };
};

let Animal = {
  walk: 'fnWalk',
  eat: 'fnEat',
  speak: 'fnSpeak',
  sleep: 'fnSleep'
};

let Duck = Object.create(Animal);
Duck.swim = 'fnSwim';

let doStuffWithAnimal = createAnimal(Duck);
doStuffWithAnimal();
```

Comment: I do have a check on the passed object's properties. I just like to add a note.

Comment: okey, but then use JSDoc, Im not sure what you asking for really :(

Comment: My problem is I don't know how to do that in JSDoc :D